# Getting reverse ManyToManyField relationship with 'through' model

Tags: django

Let's say I have following models, where I keep track of the date a person moves towns and the person's previous town info:

```
class Town(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    zipcode = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(unique=True)

class TownHistory(models.Model):
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    move_date = models.DateField()

class Person(models.model):
    towns = models.ManyToManyField(Town, through='TownHistory')
```

When going to the `town_detail` page, I'd like to get an overview (`QuerySet`) of all `Person`s that are *currently* in that `Town`.
I'm not interested in getting the `move_date`, I just want to have an overview of `Person` and *current* `Town`.

In other words: if a `Person` moved, the `QuerySet` should only contain the *latest* Town and not the previous one.

What's the most elegant solution to get this data?
I can achieve this with some hacking around, e.g.:

```
for person in Person.objects.all():
    person.townhistory_set.latest('move_date')  # add this one to a list
```

But then I'm not getting a `QuerySet` back, and I think there should be a 'cleaner' solution? I tried looking at using `Max()` as well but that didn't help.

Using Django 1.8 LTS.

Comment: Can you rework your models to track the date the person moved out of the town as well as when they moved to the town? That would simplify this immensely.

Comment: Sounds like it's a classic "lastest one for each" problem. Can you try: 
`TownHistory.objects.values('town', 'person').annotate(latest_date=Max('move_date'))`?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: not really. The above are not my real models, they're simplified ones to show the problem statement. I have a lot of additional fields in Person and Town and TownHistory.

Comment: @ShangWang: that seems helpful, but I'm getting values instead of full objects that I'd like to work with.

Comment: What objects do you need? `Person`? If so then you already had it right? `Person.objects.all()`?

Comment: @ShangWang: yes, I'm looking for a QuerySet that contains `Person`s that are currently in that `Town`. I'm not interested in the `move_date`, but if they have moved then they should not be in the QuerySet.